# Find node that has relationships with a list of nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have nodes `USERs` and nodes `CARs`. They can be connected by a relationship `LIKE`.

I would like to return all `CARs` that are `LIKEd` by a give list of `USERs`.

Currently I have this query:

```
MATCH (c:CAR)<-[r:LIKES]-(u:User) 
WHERE u.username  IN ['Sara', 'John'] RETURN e, u
```

However that returns all cars that are liked by either Sara, John or both. I would like to limit it to only cars that are liked by BOTH.

**UPDATE:**
Here's what I came up with so far, but this approach doesn't allow me to use an array of names as an input, I can work with that, but would love to find a solution that could take an array as a param, any help greatly appreciated.

```
MATCH (c:CAR) 

WHERE (c)<-[:LIKES]-(:User {username: 'Sara'}) 

AND (e)<-[:LIKES]-(:User {username: 'John'}) 
return c
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this query will meet your needs:

```
MATCH (user:USER) WHERE user.username IN ['Sara', 'John']
WITH COLLECT(id(user)) AS user_ids
MATCH (user:USER)-[:LIKES]->(car:CAR)
WHERE id(user) IN user_ids
WITH car, user_ids, COLLECT(id(user)) as ids_of_users_that_like_car
WHERE ALL(user_id IN user_ids WHERE user_id IN ids_of_users_that_like_car) 
RETURN car
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky. The easiest way I've found is to the leverage this:

> ALL(x IN y WHERE EXISTS(relationship))

Assuming a graph of Sara, John, and Bill, where all three like Mustang cars, and John and Bill like Pintos, this code would return the Mustang car, the only car liked by all users in the list:

```
WITH ['Sara', 'John', 'Bill'] AS usernames 
MATCH (c:CAR) 
WHERE ALL(username IN usernames WHERE EXISTS((:User{name:username})-[:LIKES]->(c))) 
RETURN c
```

EDIT:
Alternately, you can try this, which first matches on users on the list, matches on cars liked by those users, then narrows it down to only cars liked by all of those users.

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.name IN ['Sara', 'John', 'Bill'] 
WITH u, COLLECT(u) AS users
MATCH (u)-[:LIKES]->(c:CAR)
WHERE ALL(user IN users WHERE EXISTS((user)-[:LIKES]->(c))) 
RETURN c
```

You'll want to profile on your actual data set to see which works best.